# R: Counting values of other columns in groups in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

(Sorry about the poorly made title, wasn't sure how to phrase my question in a single sentence.)

I have a data.table of matches that is sorted chronologically, with P1 representing player1, P2 representing player2, and Res representing whether P1 won ("w") or drew ("d") against P2.
*EDIT: a, b, and c in the P1 and P2 columns represent individual players. Think of them as Alice, Bob, and Charlie.*

```
DT <- data.table(time = 1:10,
             P1 = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "b", "a", "c"),
             Res = c("d", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "d", "d", "w", "w"),
             P2 = c("b", "c", "c", "a", "a", "c", "c", "a", "b", "b"))
```

I performed the following operations to count **at the time of the match**, how many wins P1 had (wins1) and how many losses P2 had (loss2).

```
DT[, wins1 := shift(cumsum(Res == "w"), 1, fill=0L), by=P1]
DT[, loss2 := shift(cumsum(Res == "w"), 1, fill=0L), by=P2]
```

I am trying to create the columns for wins2, loss1, draw1, and draw2. 
That is, I right now have how many wins P1 had at the time of their match against P2, but I do not know how many losses they had. Hope that makes sense. I'm sure the method to creating these columns are all similar, so if I can make one I should be able to make them all.

The final table should look like the following:

```
     time P1 Res P2 wins1 loss1 draw1 wins2 loss2 draw2
 1:    1  a   d  b     0     0     0     0     0     0
 2:    2  a   w  c     0     0     1     0     0     0
 3:    3  b   w  c     0     0     1     0     1     0
 4:    4  b   w  a     1     0     1     1     0     1
 5:    5  b   w  a     2     0     1     1     1     1
 6:    6  a   w  c     1     2     1     0     2     0
 7:    7  a   d  c     2     2     1     0     3     0
 8:    8  b   d  a     3     0     1     2     2     2
 9:    9  a   w  b     2     2     2     3     0     1
10:   10  c   w  b     0     3     1     3     1     1
```

Comment: What is the significance of a, b, c for players P1 and P2?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified better. a, b, and c are individual players (Alice, Bob, Charlie).
The Res column just tells you whether the player in the P1 column won or drew against P2.
So in row 1, "a" draws against "b". In row 2, "a" wins against "c", and so on. The columns to the right tell you how many wins, losses, and draws the respective players under P1 and P2 had won at that point.

Comment: A little brute-force, but here's a starting point for you: `DT[, wins2 := DT[DT, on = .(P1 = P2, time < time), sum(Res == 'w', na.rm = T), by = .EACHI]$V1]`

Comment: `draw2` on lines 9 and 10 should be `2`, no?

Comment: Thanks! Gonna spend the next chunk of my time studying that so I can make the other columns.

No worries about it being "a little" brute force. Earlier I managed to do this myself with a for-loop but it was sooooo slow. This is definitely way faster.


EDIT: you're absolute right about draw2 being 2 on those lines. I was eye-balling it, thanks for the catch.